# Adding a column based on data in other columns

Tags: sql

I'm currently working on data analysis for a game's tutorial. I have a table with the completed steps of the tutorial. Here is a sample of what two day's worth of data currently looks like. As the tutorial increases in complexity, the amount of players that complete the next step, decreases.

| date | stepName | completionCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-08 | loadIn | 25 |
| 2022-06-08 | receiveSword | 20 |
| 2022-06-08 | defeatEnemy | 15 |
| 2022-06-08 | claimReward | 10 |
| 2022-06-08 | leaveTutorial | 5 |
| 2022-06-07 | loadIn | 45 |
| 2022-06-07 | receiveSword | 35 |
| 2022-06-07 | defeatEnemy | 20 |
| 2022-06-07 | claimReward | 15 |
| 2022-06-07 | leaveTutorial | 8 |

My goal is to include a new column with a percentage based on that day's max step count. Below is what I hope to convert the top table into. The first step, "loadIn", should always be 100% since that is the baseline for the rest of the steps.

| date | stepName | completionCount | completionPercentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-08 | loadIn | 25 | 100% |
| 2022-06-08 | receiveSword | 20 | 80% |
| 2022-06-08 | defeatEnemy | 15 | 60% |
| 2022-06-08 | claimReward | 10 | 40% |
| 2022-06-08 | leaveTutorial | 5 | 20% |
| 2022-06-07 | loadIn | 50 | 100% |
| 2022-06-07 | receiveSword | 45 | 90% |
| 2022-06-07 | defeatEnemy | 40 | 80% |
| 2022-06-07 | claimReward | 20 | 40% |
| 2022-06-07 | leaveTutorial | 15 | 30% |

I am VERY new to SQL and could really use some help here. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain how, for the last row in your example, you arrived at 30%? the day's (2022-06-07) total is 50+45+40+20+15=170, how does 15 translate to 30% of 170?
Also, you need something to sort the steps, do they have a sequence # somewhere we can use or do you expect to hardcode them according to your sample?

Comment: OP is saying that the denominator needs to be the loadIn number for each day, so it would be 15/50 = 30%

Comment: What SQL are you wanting to use? MS SQL? Oracle SQL? Other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
select 
  *, 
  max(completitionCount) OVER(partition by date) as dailymax,
  completitionCount/dailymax as completionPercentage
from yourtable
```

Because your loadIn number is consistently the highest number each day, a window function using `MAX()` is appropriate in this scenario.
Here's a reference to [redshift MAX() window function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_MAX.html)